# Valid Json in Mapping Templates API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am working with AWS API Gateway and Lambda, I am trying to passe a valid Json object to the Lambda function to avoid sanitizing the data in the function.
Using this code:

```
"params" : "$input.params()",
```

will result in this data being sent to the Lambda function:

```
"params" : "{path={}, querystring={src_build=rfsdfsdf}, header={}}",
```

Is there a solution get the $input.params as a valide json dictionary ?

Comment: Give this tutorial a read: https://github.com/mauerbac/lambda-gateway-twilio-demo

Comment: You didn't even understand my question! My question is how can you generate a valide json parameter in the params entry ! if you see the result of "$input.params()" you will see there is "=" in the generated result, and that is not json valide!

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be just `$input.json('$')`.

[image]

I based this answer on information from [API Gateway Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-dg.pdf).

Comment: That will give you the body of the HTTP request, I am talking about the parameters, like the path, the querystring and the HEADERS.

Comment: This isn't clear from your question. Let me see if that can be done.